# Application built with Xcode 5 - submission to app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode5, xcode5.1

I have created an application using Xcode 5 IDE, and it is ready to be submitted to the App Store , is there any possibility that apple would reject it if it's not built with Xcode 5.1 IDE ? I didn't yet install it. Is there any official memo saying that apps would get rejected if not built with Xcode 5.1? I know that apple won't accept any application built with any IDE lower than Xcode 5

Comment: Out of interest how come you don't want to upgrade? :)

Comment: @Rich of course i'm gonna upgrade, but reading the reviews about Xcode 5.1 i wasn't exactly encouraged to do that ! so i don't want to take any chances considering the submission phase of this app , there's a deadline really near ! but the upgrade will surely be built with Xcode 5.1 , and can i download a standalone version of it without overriding Xcode 5 ??

Comment: Ah fair enough :) Don't be discouraged by the reviews, I found Xcode 5.1 to be much better! And you can indeed have 2 different versions installed and use `xcode-select` to pick the one you want.

Comment: @Rich yea i know that, considering i still have on my device Xcode 4.4 , Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5  :P , but i searched the internet to find a source of download other than the App Store..cz app store will automatically override my current version, do you have any idea how can i do it ? ( i +1 your answer as a thank you for the relief !! )

Comment: You can download Xcode 5.1 directly from the [iOS dev center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#downloads) as a standalone download! (You'll need to sign in to access that link though)

Comment: @Rich my friend you are an angel !!! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, apple haven't announced anything around this (yet) so you should be fine. Last time (with [iOS 6](http://www.imore.com/apple-tells-developers-apps-must-be-optimized-ios-7-february-1-2014) / Xcode 4.6) they announced it about a couple of months before hand.

EDIT: The [Apple dev site](https://developer.apple.com/ios7/#download) also says Xcode 5 still

Comment: thank you for your fast reply :) and thank you for putting my mind at ease ! i will accept your answer in 10 minutes as per stack's rules

Comment: @EliasRahme no problem! I'm just finding some references to improve the answer too!